# convert .ods with multiple sheets to 1 or multiple .csv files

Tags: php, ods

I am actually using a php script to import a `.ods` file and convert it to `.csv` in order to add, finally everything to an SQL table but when I upload a multiple sheets `ods` file it only converts the first sheet.

To convert it I use the command (broken onto two lines for readability):

```
$ libreoffice4.2 --headless --invisible \
                 --convert-to csv /tmp/test.ods --outdir /tmp/
```

How do I process the other sheets as well?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to that question. Did you find a solution since you posted this question half a year ago?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same problem, here is how I solved it:

Taking as reference the answer in [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/47097/how-do-i-export-all-sheets-from-a-spreadsheet/), I built this libreoffice base script:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub convertSheetsToCSVs
Dim fileProps(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
sheets = ThisComponent.Sheets

fileProps(0).Name = "FilterName"
fileProps(0).Value = "Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)"
fileProps(1).Name = "FilterOptions"
fileProps(1).Value = "09,,22,1,,0,false,true"

'The previous line can be changed to modify filter options as explained in 
'https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Filter_Options_for_the_CSV_Filter

folder = "file:///home/your_folder_path/"
i = 0

Do While sheets.Count > i
  sheet = sheets.getByIndex(i)
  cntrllr = ThisComponent.CurrentController
  cntrllr.setActiveSheet(sheet)
  sURL = folder & sheets.ElementNames(i) & ".csv"
  ThisComponent.storeToURL(sURL, fileProps())
  i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

If you want to do it in the console, surely there is a way, but I do not know how.